# Rails is adding an "id" to the end of my link using the Hash Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

The "a href" works as planned but the "Link_to" is adding an "id" to the end of the "hello" action directing me to demo/helloid instead of demo/hello. See Rails .erb code below

```
<h1>Demo#index</h1>
<p>Hello From index!!</p>

<a href="/demo/hello">Hello page 1</a><br />

<%= link_to "Hello Page 2", ({ controller: "demo", action: "hello"}) %>
```

While looking in at the HTML source it presents the following

```
<h1>Demo#index</h1>
<p>Hello From index!!</p>

<a href="/demo/hello">Hello page 1</a><br />

<a href="/demo/helloid">Hello Page 2</a>
```

Routes

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "demo#index" 
  #get 'demo/index'
  match ':controller(/:action(id))', :via => :get
```

Controller

```
    class DemoController < ApplicationController

    layout false

    def index
    end

    def hello
        #render('hello')
        @array = [1,2,3,4,5]
    end

    def other_hello
        redirect_to(:controller => 'demo', :action => 'index')
    end

end
```

Comment: could you provide `routes.rb` and controller code?

Comment: please post your routes file

Comment: also have tried something like this eg. `link_to "Profile", { controller: "profiles", action: "show", id: @profile}`

Comment: I edited the controller and routes file in

Comment: I'm confused what the actual question is.  What is it doing versus what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: I edited my post to restate the issue the clearly. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route is incorrect on the following line:

```
match ':controller(/:action(id))',   :via => :get   # Incorrect AND unnecessary
```

Additionally, this route does not even need to exist because Rails can do this for you using the `url_for` method:

```
<%= link_to "Hello Page 2", url_for(controller: "demo", action: "hello") %>
```

As long as there is a route with the appropriate controller/action assigned in routes.rb, this will generate the URL for that specific route.

[> Read the Rails url_for Docs here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor/url_for)

Comment: I also would recommend to read about routing in Rails here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html  TL;DR; Change your route to `get '/demo/hello', to: 'demo#hello'`